# Кастомная карусель на Angular 2/4

Tags: angular2

Нужно на фон приложения установить background-image. Картинок несколько. Выбрал вариант с использованием TimerObservable. 
Теперь возникла проблема, что бы сделать плавную анимацию. Возможно знаете иные способы достижения такого эфекта? Или как анимировать.

```
<div class="slide" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': url }" ></div>


    image: String[] = [
    '../img/food1.jpg',
    '../img/food2.jpg',
    '../img/food3.jpg'
  ];

  subscription: any;
  time: number = 0;
  url: string;      

  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = TimerObservable.create(1000,5000);
    this.subscription = timer.subscribe(t=>{
      this.url =  `url(${this.image[this.time++]})`;          
      this.time > 2 ? this.time = 0 : null;

    })
  }
```

Comment: чтобы сделать анимацию, надо почитать как https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: @Artsiom читал, но она всё равно работает не корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавив еще один div

```
<div class="shadow" *ngIf="!showDiv" [@flyInOut] [ngStyle]="{'background-image': url }"></div>
<div class="slide" *ngIf="showDiv" [@flyInOut] [ngStyle]="{'background-image': url }" ></div>
```

Также код анимации

```
 animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      transition('void => *', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate(2000)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(2000, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

И код компонента

```
  image: String[] = [
    '../img/food1.jpg',
    '../img/food2.jpg',
    '../img/food3.jpg'
  ];
  showDiv: boolean = true;
  subscription: any;
  time: number = 0;
  url: string;
  opacity: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    let timer = TimerObservable.create(1000,5000);
    this.subscription = timer.subscribe(t=>{
      this.showDiv = this.showDiv  ? false : true;
      console.log(this.showDiv);
      //this.opacity = `opacity 5s infinite`;
      this.url =  `url(${this.image[this.time++]})`;
      this.time > 2 ? this.time = 0 : null;
    })
  }
```